# How can I make my fixed navbar side menu button show all menu items on hover. Hover works on sub menus but not on the "button" here are my scripts:

Tags: html, css, button, hover, navbar

```
    @media (min-width:769px) { //this displays hover effect on sub menus but not "button"/
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    }
    ul .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
      display:none;
    }

<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top side-menu right-slide-menu" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-rj-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

        .navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
      p
```

//I have tried to change "toggle" to hover to no avail.
And I apologize Jean-Maxine//

Comment: Can you post your HTML code please ?

Comment: Sorry here it is:   
    <div class="navbar-trigger-open right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
   
    
    <nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top side-menu right-slide-menu" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-rj-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

Comment: Edit your post ;)